# API Endpoint not responding anything

Tags: javascript, api, oauth

I am trying to access this API https://dev.openclinica.com/apidoc/#api-Study-getStudyMetadata but for some reason the Api is not returning anything, its just empty response.

This is the API that I am calling: http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica/pages/odmk/studies/S_PROSPER/metadata

I am stuck on here and have no idea how do I use their API.

Comment: It appears the instance of that API is not working properly. I can't seem to get any responses outside of 200 codes

Comment: @Brennan what do u really mean by instance of the API, could you explain in more details? is somthing wrong the the API itself?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. The body of every response is completely empty, which is suspicious. Seems the API hosted at the URL you shared doesn't work

Comment: @Brennan how about this one: http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica/pages/auth/api/v1/system/modules/webservices , it asks me for username and password which I have no idea what username pass to enter, I am trying the login credentials login password but that does not seem working...